# Test if rectangle contains all or part of another rectangle?

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I have this code:

```
graphicsContext.setCanvas(canvas);
graphicsContext.clear();
camera.applyTransform(graphicsContext);
RectF screen = camera.getCamRect(getWidth(), getHeight());

for(Road r : roads) {
  if(screen.contains(r.getRect())) {
    r.draw(graphicsContext);
  }
}

for(Intersection i : intersections) {
  if(screen.contains(i.getRect())) {
    i.draw(graphicsContext);
  }
}
```

The only problem is the contains method must have all 4 verticies of B in A to return true.
What type of algorithm could I use, given top, left, bottom, right to check if B is either part or completely inside B.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `RectF.contains()` with each of the vertices of the shape you want to test for intersection

or even easier, `RectF.intersects()` will handle all that for you.

It's all in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RectF.html).

Comment: isn't intersects positive for partial match (not full rect) ?

Comment: No, `intersects()` will return true for partial overlap and full overlap - both count as intersection. You can check the source code at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/RectF.java

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `intersects` method instead:

```
for(Road r : roads)
{
    if(RectF.intersects(screen, r.getRect()))
    {
        r.draw(graphicsContext);
    }
}
```